# Bad mask for Cisco simulator GNS3

Tags: cisco, ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address

I am using the GNS3 simulator, and I need to connect two Cisco C7200 routers.

When I enter the `ip address 126.0.0.4 255.255.255.252` command, I get `Bad mask /30 for address 126.0.0.4`.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `126.0.0.4/30` is the network address, not a host address. See the answer to [How do you calculate the prefix, network, subnet, and host numbers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) for how to calculate that.

For a `/30` network, there are two host addresses: `subnet + 1` and `subnet + 2`. In your particular example, that would be `126.0.0.5` and `126.0.0.6`.

Answer (score 2):

126.0.0.4/30 is the network address. To work, the IP of the first host should be 126.0.0.5/30(Gateway) and the second host 126.0.0.6/30